# Separate table columns into different tables

Tags: jquery, html

I have a task to separate n-columns table each column to different tables.

My idea in that:

1. I have `th` in each column.
2. So `th` may be a detector of new column.
3. I need to find `tr td` in each column.
4. I need to create new table-N with `th-N value` in `th`
5. I need to paste each `tr td-N` after `th`

So according to my idea, I have written following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function tableshoot() {

        $("table th").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var thistext = $this.html();
            var index = $this.index();

            var tdList = $this.closest("table").find("tr").find("td:eq(" + index + ")").html();

            $this.closest("table").append('<table class="mob-table-' + index + '"><tbody><tr><th>' + thistext + '</th></tr></tbody></table>');

            $this.closest("table").find("tr").find("td:eq(" + index + ")").each(function() {
                var tdcontent = $(this).html();
                $('table.mob-table-' + index + ' tbody').append('<tr><td>' + tdcontent + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });

    };
    tableshoot();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        COL 1
      </th>
      <th>
        COL 2
      </th>
      <th>
        COL 3
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VAL 1</td>
      <td>VAL 2</td>
      <td>VAL 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VAL 11</td>
      <td>VAL 22</td>
      <td>VAL 33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VAL 111</td>
      <td>VAL 222</td>
      <td>VAL 333</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My question is:

Is it right way? Or are there more clean ways to do it?

No matter my code is workable. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Few small things:

1. "find("tr").find("td:eq(..." change to "find(tr td:eq..."
2. "$("table th").each(function()" change to "$("table th").each(function(index, value)", for clean access to index and value.

[jQuery doc each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)